# How to configure Swagger In ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to implement/configure Swagger in my project.

I have installed (Swashbuckle) package which is necessary for swagger implementation.

Where should I need to add the swagger configuration or which file should I have to include.

Comment: https://code-maze.com/swagger-ui-asp-net-core-web-api/

Comment: Did you even try to read the documentation before coming here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will create an project from correct template it already comes with Swagger pre-setup. For example you can use the ASP.NET Core web API template (via your IDE or using [`dotnet new` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) with [`webapi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#webapi) template name). It includes (for .NET 7):

- Preinstalled packages:

  ```xml
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.7"/>
  <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0"/>
  ```
- Swagger set up (in `Program.cs`):

  ```cs
  // ...
  builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

  // ...

  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) // by default enabled only for dev.
  {
       app.UseSwagger();
       app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }
  ```

Read also:

- [`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`: Getting Started](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

.NET 7 WebAPI project you need to configure it on `Program.cs` file.

You need to add Swagger generator to the services collection.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//Add the Swagger generator to the services collection
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Example to configure Swagger with JWT Authorization is as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{ }
        }
    });
});
```